# nodemailer with GoDaddy on Heroku and getting Error 502 - Bad Gateway

Tags: javascript, heroku

I am trying to setup nodemailer to work with my GoDaddy email account so I can send out a password reset email to users.  I keep getting Error 502 - Bad Gateway.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is my code**

```js
function(token, user, done) {
   var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Office365",
        host: "smtp.office365.com",  
        secureConnection: true,
        port: 587,
        
        auth: {
        user: "john@mydomain.com",
        pass: process.env.EMAILPW
     },
     tls: {
         ciphers: "SSLv3"
     }
```

Comment: Would it not also require the host, port, etc?

Comment: I just updated my code with what Godaddy told me to do and it still isn't working.

Comment: Is the error still the same?

Comment: Yes.  I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After many many many hours, I figured out how to setup GoDaddy Office365 on nodemailer.

Here is my code that worked.

```js
 var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "Office365",
            host: "smtp.office365.com",  
            secureConnection: false,
            port: 25,
            auth: {
            user: "john@mydomain.com",
            pass: process.env.EMAILPW
            },
            tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

After more review, my original code works also.  It just doesn't work in Cloud 9 but when I pushed it to Heroku it works fine.  Still not sure why it wouldn't work on Cloud 9.